# Fortran mismatch in argument

Tags: fortran, mismatch

My compiler shows this error

`Warning: Rank mismatch in argument ‘change’ at (1) (scalar and rank-2) [-Wargument-mismatch]`

The argument change is in subroutine solve_pos_eq, and here is the code

```
program poisson
  implicit none
  integer :: ni,nj 
  real :: h_size 
  integer :: ii,jj ! For loops
  real(16) :: change,accuracy 
  real(16),allocatable :: uij(:,:), uij_new(:,:), q_den(:,:)



  write(*,*) "Enter number of cells in x and y, and cell size:"
  read(*,*) ni,nj,h_size
  write(*,*) "Enter desired accuracy:"
  read(*,*) accuracy

  allocate(uij(0:ni+1,0:nj+1))
  allocate(uij_new(0:ni+1,0:nj+1))
  allocate(q_den(0:ni+1,0:nj+1))

  do ii=1,ni
    q_den(ii,1:nj)=4.0*ii
  end do


call solve_pos_eq(accuracy,h_size,ni,nj,q_den,uij_new,uij,change)

  do ii=0,ni+1
     write(*,'(*(es16.4e2))') uij_new(ii,:)
  end do

  deallocate(uij)
  deallocate(uij_new)
  deallocate(q_den)

  stop 0

end program poisson

subroutine solve_pos_eq(accuracy,h_size,ni,nj,q_den,uij_new,change,uij)
  implicit none

  integer,intent(in) :: ni,nj ! input cell number in the x and y direct
  real,intent(in) :: h_size 
  integer :: ii,jj 
  real(16),intent(out) :: change,accuracy 
  ! Allocatable arrays to store potentials and charge density
  real(16),intent(in) ::  q_den(0:ni+1,0:nj+1)
  real(16),intent(out) :: uij_new(0:ni+1,0:nj+1), uij(0:ni+1,0:nj+1)

  uij=0.0
  uij_new=0.0

  do
     change=0.0 !

     do jj = 1, nj
        do ii = 1,ni

           uij_new(ii,jj)=0.25*( uij(ii+1,jj)+uij(ii-1,jj)+uij(ii,jj+1) &
                & +uij(ii,jj-1)-16.0*atan(1.0)*q_den(ii,jj)*h_size**2 )

           if (abs(uij_new(ii,jj)-uij(ii,jj)) > change) then
              change=abs(uij_new(ii,jj)-uij(ii,jj))

           end if

        end do ! ii
     end do ! jj


     if (change < accuracy) then
        write(*,*) "Reached required accuracy"
        exit
     end if

     uij=uij_new

  end do 

  return
end subroutine solve_pos_eq
```

I figured that the call and subroutine arguments don't match. I should have switched change and uij.

call solve_pos_eq(accuracy,h_size,ni,nj,q_den,uij_new,**uij,change**)

subroutine solve_pos_eq(accuracy,h_size,ni,nj,q_den,uij_new,**change,uij**)

Comment: Please show at least how the subroutine is called, and the declaration of all the variables. Much better would be a complete code which generates the same warning

Comment: You have `..., uij,change` in the argument list when calling, but the subroutine has `..., change,uij`.

Comment: Oh I didn't know it has to be in order, thanks for the help!

Comment: If you put your subroutines in a module this would fail to compile, and you would see your problem straight away

Comment: Can you make your example minimal following [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?